# Split if two consecutive characters are not same

Tags: python-2.7, split

I have a input string like

```
a = '4433555555666666'
```

i want the values to be separated if last character is not same as the next one.

in this case:

```
44, 33, 555555, 666666
```

I'm new in python so don't know how to deal with it. I have tried but it just gives first one correct i.e.

```
['44', '', '555555666666']
```

Also if two consecutive character group is same.
i.e.
        a = 'chchdfch'
then 'ch' should be replaced with
        a = '**df*'

Comment: can I group them with step=2 i mean if there is something like `string = "4545558545"` then replacing each 45 with 'a' which should look like `string= "aa5585a"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
[''.join(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(a)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = '4433555555666666'
>>> [''.join(value) for key, value in itertools.groupby(a)]
['44', '33', '555555', '666666']
```

So this code is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) - a compact way of iterating over elements individually.

Another way of representing this is:

```
>>> for k, v in itertools.groupby(a):
...   print k, v
... 
4 <itertools._grouper object at 0x100b90710>
3 <itertools._grouper object at 0x100b90750>
5 <itertools._grouper object at 0x100b90710>
6 <itertools._grouper object at 0x100b90750>
>>> for k, v in itertools.groupby(a):
...   print k, "".join(v) 
... 
4 44
3 33
5 555555
6 666666
>>>
```

Just ignore the `k` the iterator generates.

Comment: thnx it worked for me. but i don't know whats happening. can you explain the code or any simpler way for it?
also i want to keep the maximum len of group == 3

Comment: Now, i tried to expand the looping construct for better understanding. I will let you figure out the max length of the group clause because it is very straight forward. If you are stuck for too long, let me know.

Comment: thnk you for explanation. yes i can figure out the max length. thnk you once again. :)